# Javascript array change in realtime after button click

Tags: javascript

i'm making a web application which helps people to seek what disease they have according to the symptoms.

I want to the user to click specific symptom to add in the "u_symptom_i" array and show all of the changed array elements by alert function

However, i cannot see the added element by alert function

```
    <script>
      var j = 0;
      while(j < escaped_cc.length) {
        document.write('<th><button id="symptom_button">' + escaped_cc[j] + '</button></th>');
        document.getElementById("symptom_button").value = escaped_cc[j];
        j = j + 1;
      }

      $("button").click(function() {
          u_symptom_i.push($(this).val());
          alert($(this).val());
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor HERE instead of relying on external sites that can change at any time

Comment: Remove the github link, post the relevant code here, on-site.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h2>Insert Array</h2>
<input type="text" id="example" name="value">
<button id="button">Add array new item</button>
</body>
<script>
var array=[];
$("#button").click(function() {
  var str = $("#example").val();
  array.push(str);
  alert(array);
});
</script>
</html>
```

Can you try this code? Adds each new value entered to an array named array and displays the records.

Comment: I would be glad if you can press the up arrow next to the question